# How to show AlertDialog When Application in Foreground Android?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a program is responsible for show AlertDialog when it in foreground after several seconds:

```
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemServ();
    if (am != null) {
        List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
        if (taskInfo != null && !taskInfo.isEmpty()) {
            if (taskInfo.get(0) != null && taskInfo.get(0).topActivity != null) {
                if (!MY_CLASS_NAME.equalsIgnoreCase(taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName())) {

                    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA?")
                    .setTitle("Message").setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {                                

                        }  
                    })  
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){

                        }
                    }).show();                      
                }
            }
        }                       
    }
```

But AlertDialog didn't show when app go to foreground! Pls help me! Thanks!

Comment: are you sure your id-else conditions leads correctly to AlertDialog? can you log any message to verify that conditions are working fine?

Comment: Where are you running this code? In an Activity or Service?

Comment: @alexanderblom
In Service : i hava timerTask
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
           showAlertDialog();
}

Comment: @Waqas :
I debuged and also sys out! And it lead correctly to AlertDialog!

Comment: I dont think you can show **AlertDialog** from service because it needs reference to your activity's context. Instead, you should rely on `Toast` pop-up messages which can be displayed using application's context

Comment: i used both Toast and AlertDialog! Didn't work! Thanks for reply! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't show a Dialog from a Service. Instead use an Activity themed like a Dialog, set the theme for the Activity (in the manifest) like this:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

Also, you shouldn't use `TimerTask`, use `Handler` instead, like this: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html

Comment: Your mean is create new Activity with Dialog Theme! And call it when App in foreground?

Comment: Yes, this will behave as you want. You need to do it this way because you can't launch an Dialog from the background.

Comment: Thanks for help! I can't vote for u beacause i have not enough reputation! :) And we are same age! :)

Comment: You should be able to accept the answer though, have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

Use create() method to create the dialog box like this:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA?")
                        .setTitle("Message").setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {                                

                        }  
                    })  
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){

                        }
                    }).create().show();
```

Comment: if you simply want to show AlertDialog without setting its reference to an **AlertDialog** object, then you don't really need to call `create()` before `show()`. You may directly call `show()` to pop dialog

Answer (score 0):

I just modified your code. Please check and update in your code snippet:

```
 ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemServ();
if (am != null) {
    List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
    if (taskInfo != null && !taskInfo.isEmpty()) {
        if (taskInfo.get(0) != null && taskInfo.get(0).topActivity != null) {
            if (!MY_CLASS_NAME.equalsIgnoreCase(taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName())) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setMessage("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA?")
                .setTitle("Message").setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {                                

                    }  
                })  
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){

                    }
                });             
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();  
    alert.show();       
            }
        }
    }                       
}
```

Comment: no error! just still not display AlertDialog! If application in background it's ok, but foreground it not